# Django 3.0.5 User Authenticate with Username or Email

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication, model

i'm struggling a bit with this problem, some says i have to override AuthenticationForm but i don't know how cause i got a custom user registration and login, i'll post it:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

Note im using default loginview right now.

So in views.py i must have this

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, '/login.html')
    ...
    ...
```

Of course login.html is just like this

```
<div class='container'>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>
        you can login here!
    </p>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type='submit'>Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

In models.py my custom user is this one:

```
class ProfiloUtente(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    utente = models.ForeignKey(Utente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studio = models.ManyToManyField(Studio)
    telefono_fisso = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None, blank=True)
    telefono_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None, blank=True)
    indirizzo = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=None, blank=True)
    citta = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, blank=True)
    cap = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=None, blank=True)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=None, blank=True)
    cod_fiscale = models.CharField(max_length=16, default=None, blank=True)
    p_iva = models.CharField(max_length=27, default=None, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And the fields i use from The default django user are these:
forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """docstring for RegistrationForm"""
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)


    class Meta: # define a metadata related to this class
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password1',
            'password2',

        )
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']


        if commit:
            user.save() # running sql in database to store data
        return user
```

could someone help me figure out how could i manage to authenticate this user by using Email or Username?
Every help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to authenticate your user using an email address, you have to make a custom user. And after defining fields for the custom user, you write **USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'**. Only by writing this, django will change the user authentication and require an email. I also have a question containing my custom user... you can check the code here [Field Error during Password reset in Django custom user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62177852/field-error-during-password-reset-in-django-custom-user)
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's supported out of the box.

Do [this](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). You don't need social account providers if you don't want to support it.

Additional configuration:

```py
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
# Recommended
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
```