# Field Error during Password reset in Django custom user

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a custom User in my django app. And when I submit an email to reset password in the the built in password reset form, I get the following error

**FieldError at /password_reset/
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field.** Choices are: active, address, admin, bio, company_category, company_desc, company_name, company_site, country, designation, email, first_name, grad_year, id, last_login, last_name, linkedin, logentry, markets, no_employees, password, phone, photo, resume, staff, technologies, university

My custom user model and model manager are as follows:

```
# -----------------------------  USER MANAGER -----------------------------
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user_obj = self.model(
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj


    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        staff=True,
        admin=True
        )
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True
        )
        return user



# ----------------------------- CUSTOM USER -----------------------------

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email               = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name          = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    resume              =  models.FileField(upload_to='res/', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='resume')
    photo               = models.ImageField(upload_to='pi/', default='img/default.png', blank=True, null=True)
    bio                 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    designation         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    university          = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company_name        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    grad_year           = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    phone               = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address             = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country             = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company_category    = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    company_desc        = models.CharField(max_length=800, blank=False)
    company_site        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    no_employees        = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    technologies        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    markets             = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    linkedin            = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin               = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  #python manage.py createsuperuser asks for these fields

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


    def get_full_name(self):
        if self.full_name:
            return self.full_name
        else:
            return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: It seems that you have the `is_active` field in the form and the form tries to save it as if it's a real field of user table. Please give the property setter for the `is_active`. And I am wondering why you didn't use `active` directly. Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: Well I am not overriding the default password reset form of django i.e. I'm using it as it is. But I guess there is no is_active field in it.... Plus there were errors because django was confused about where to use which "active". So, the only solution I saw on stackoverflow was to use is_active as well as active